# onPostExecute() doesn't run sometimes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a weird problem with my AsyncTask. If I call my AsyncTask there is no problem but if I call it from a static method of another class or call it on another objects method onPostExecute doesn't run. I don't think I should post code because I don't think it is about code but I can it in add if you want.

Edit:

With the code I post onPostExecute doesn't called. But if I create my Bağlantı object from my activity it Works like it supposed to.

Edit:   Added code. Sorry it is a little it complex

From my activity class named "ExplorerActivity" :

```
Gönderi deneme = new Gönderi( "10|44|Deneme|12|12,24", this);
```

From my class creating flexible views named "Gönderi" :

```
Profil gönderenProfil;

        if( Ayarlar.sProfiller.containsKey( mGönderenId ) ){

            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) pActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifi = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            NetworkInfo mobile = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if ( !wifi.isConnected() && !mobile.isConnected() ) 
                gönderenProfil = Ayarlar.sProfiller.get( mGönderenId );

            else
                gönderenProfil = Ayarlar.sProfiller.get( mGönderenId ).güncelle( pActivity );

        }

        else{
            gönderenProfil = new Profil( Ayarlar.sMevcutId, pActivity);

            Ayarlar.sProfiller.put( mGönderenId,  gönderenProfil);
        }
```

From my class which contains profile information name "Profil" :

```
public Profil( String id, Activity pActivity ) {
        mID = new String( id );

        String değerler[] = new String[1];

        değerler[0] = id;

        Bağlantı2 bağlantı = new Bağlantı2( Bağlantı2.BağlantıTipi.AL_KİŞİ, değerler, pActivity );
        bağlantı.bağlan();

        do{
            //Bağlantı tamamlanana kadar bekle
        }while( bağlantı.mKullanımda );

        if( bağlantı.mSonuç != Bağlantı2.Sonuç.BAŞARILI )
            return;

        mİndirildi = true;

        String dönüt = bağlantı.mDönüt;

    ....

    }

public Profil güncelle( Activity pActivity ){


        String değerler[] = new String[1];

        değerler[0] = mID;

        Bağlantı2 bağlantı = new Bağlantı2( BağlantıTipi.AL_KİŞİ, değerler, pActivity );
        bağlantı.bağlan();

        do{
            //Bağlantı tamamlanana kadar bekle
        }while( bağlantı.mKullanımda );

        if( bağlantı.mSonuç != Bağlantı2.Sonuç.BAŞARILI )
            return this;

        mİndirildi = true;

        ...

        return this;
    }
```

From my connection class named "Bağlantı" :

```
public void bağlan(){

        mKullanımda = true;
        ++sAktifBağlantıSayısı;

        Log.i( TAG , "Aktif bağlantı sayısı: " + sAktifBağlantıSayısı );

        switch( mTip ){ 

                 //Deleted this part because it contains database password and url etc.     

        }

        try{
            mURL = new URL( sAnaUrl + mLink );

        }catch(MalformedURLException e1){
            mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ ;
            mNeden = Neden.URL;
        }


        try{
            new BağlantıTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }catch( Exception e ){

            }

    }

    class BağlantıTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //uzun islem oncesi yapilacaklar
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... foo) {
            //uzun islem sirasinda yapilacaklar


            if( mSonuç == Bağlantı2.Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ ){
                return null;
            }

            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifi = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            NetworkInfo mobile = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if ( !wifi.isConnected() && !mobile.isConnected() ) {
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.BAĞLANTIHATASI;
                return null;
            }


            try {
                HttpGet mGet = new HttpGet( mURL.toString());

                Log.w( "link" , mLink);

                mDönüt = EntityUtils.toString(mClient.execute( mGet ).getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8 );

                Log.w( "dönüt" , mDönüt);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.HTTP;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.HTTP;
            }

            --sAktifBağlantıSayısı;

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //uzun islem bitince yapilacaklar

            Log.w( TAG, "onPostExecute");

            if( mDönüt == null ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.BAĞLANTIHATASI;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "error" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.BELİRSİZ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "success" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.BELİRSİZ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "started" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.BAŞLADI;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "sent" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.GÖNDERİLDİ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "added" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.EKLENDİ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "changed" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.DEĞİŞTİRİLDİ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "exist" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.MEVCUT;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "sent" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.GÖNDERİLDİ;
            }
            else{
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.BELİRSİZ;
            }

            switch( mNeden ){

            case MEVCUT:
                Toast.makeText( mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Eposta adresi kullanımda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case BAĞLANTIHATASI:
                Toast.makeText( mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "İnternet bağlantınızı kontrol edin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case URL:
                Log.i( TAG , "-url hatası");
                break;

            case HTTP:
                Log.i( TAG , "-http hatası");
                break;

            case BELİRSİZ:
                if( mTip == Bağlantı2.BağlantıTipi.GİRİŞ && mSonuç == Bağlantı2.Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ )
                    Toast.makeText( mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Eposta ya da şifre hatalı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if( mTip == Bağlantı2.BağlantıTipi.GÖNDER_GÖNDERİ && mSonuç == Bağlantı2.Sonuç.BAŞARILI )
                    Toast.makeText( mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Gönderildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                else if( mTip == Bağlantı2.BağlantıTipi.GÖNDER_GÖNDERİ )
                    Toast.makeText( mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Gönderilemedi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.i( TAG , "-neden belirsiz");
                break;

            case KURULMADI:
                Log.i( TAG , "-kurulmadı");
                break;
            }

            mKullanımda = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh no no no. Never use special characters for variable names :-(

Comment: Sorry for it but I should make it as meaningful as possible for others who I work with. If you want I can try my best to change special characters.

Comment: You're using Turkish Characters for class and variable names. That's too bad for readability. And one more thing, you must initialise and call your `AsyncTask` like 
`BağlantıTask task = new BağlantıTask();
task.execute();`
`

Comment: I changed that part to what you said. I am coding just for one year and it is my first real roject so I don't have that kind of experience. Thanks for the tip. I will try to avoid Turkish characters next time.

Comment: By the way if I don't think wrong onPostExecute creates a Looper to runOnUi. There may be a problem about Looper because when I call Looper.prepare(); in my Activity class it throws RuntimeEception and says only one Looper may be created per thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution for my problem but it doesn't seem a good solution to me but problem isn't related to my code and I saw some people had this problem with no solutions too. Here is my solution:

```
try{
    BağlantıTask task = new BağlantıTask();
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).get();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

//I have called my AsyncTask this way and put onPostExecute part in a runUiThread.


    mActivity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if( mDönüt == null ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.BAĞLANTIHATASI;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "error" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARISIZ;
                mNeden = Neden.BELİRSİZ;
            }
            else if( mDönüt.contains( "success" ) ){
                mSonuç = Sonuç.BAŞARILI;
                mNeden = Neden.BELİRSİZ;
                    }
        ........
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very bad idea to have an empty `catch` body. It may lead to errors being hidden. Try using:

```
catch(IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a "printStackTrace" in all catch statements, maybe catch an exception.

Try to call your AsyncTask this way:

```
BağlantıTask task = new BağlantıTask();
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: I did this but didn't help